# Select records basing on field value contains in another json field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I need to select all records where json field value based on another field of this record
I have record with fields:

```
credentials: {stripe: {api_key: xxx, connected: true, enabled: true}, amazon_pay: {api_key: xxx, connected: true, enabled: true}}
payment_method: 'stripe'
```

So I need to select from credentials based on what payment_method I have   only records where this payment method enabled == true, how can I do it with SQL?

UPDATE:
I think it's must be something like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM accounts as main_query
INNER JOIN shops ON shops.id = main_query.shop_id
WHERE shops.status = 2
AND (((credentials->(SELECT sub_query.card_method FROM accounts as sub_query WHERE main_query.id = sub_query.id))::json->>'enabled')::boolean IS TRUE)
```

Comment: It would be really helpful if you could provide a SQLFiddle with some data and the expected output.

Comment: @Bustikiller update my question